# GET Request syntax

Tags: java

```
String filename = "sample.html";

String sendMessage = "GET " +filename+ " HTTP/1.1 \n";
```

Could some one please tel me whether this is the correct way to send a "GET" request to the sever?

Comment: Look here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests or here: https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/

Comment: The method described works fine for a webpage. In my case, i am requesting a html page which is located in my local system.

Answer (score 1):

you also should include the path "/etc/etc/" and finish with CR LF
here is a properly formatted basic HTTP GET

```
GET /sample.html HTTP/1.1\r\n
```